# Efficient computation of Wigner function from density matrix

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

I would like to visualize $W(X,P)=W(\alpha,\alpha^*)$ from a given density matrix $\hat{\rho}$ that has been obtained before e.g. from the master equation. I am especially interested in density matrices describing a single bosonic mode with Kerr nonlinearity and expressed in Fock states up to some cutoff $N_{\text{cutoff}}\sim 50$. The states are expected to be quite similar to a gaussian state (as a matter of fact, when it is known that the state is truly Gaussian, the Wigner function can readily be obtained from correlation functions, but I explicitly want to see how far this gaussian approximation is from the true state.)

My initial take at calculating the wigner function is using the Characteristic function:
$$\chi_W(\lambda,\lambda^*)=Tr\left\{\rho \exp(\lambda a^\dagger-\lambda^*a) \right\}\\
W(\alpha,\alpha^*)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int d^2\lambda \exp(-\lambda\alpha^*+\lambda^*\alpha)\,\chi_W(\lambda,\lambda^*)  $$ 
Unfortunately, for let's say a 100x100 grid in the $\alpha$- and $\lambda$-planes the integral sums over 10^8 terms, which takes ages (a day) to evaluate to get a result that is of a too low quality.

I found [here](http://www.photonicquantum.info/Tools.html) a program which uses an alternative approach based on Laguerre polynomials (I haven't found where their algorithm stems from unfortunately). This is already significantly faster (~30 minutes) and gives a meaningful, smooth 'mountain' in phase space corresponding to the state of the system, but aside from that also a giant noisy ring around the origin of fluctuations (I thought for a while this could be physical interference, but it is too irregular and doesn't disappear when feeding a $\hat{\rho}$ that is explicitly gaussian thus classical).

The last source I found is [this github](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/pull/461/files) page, but it is not entirely transparant to me (partly because I'm unfamiliar with the language). It does tell me that FFT is also an option, though I don't know how to do that for an integral over the whole complex plane.

I prefer to work with MATLAB, but Mathematica is also an option.

Comment: I've always thought Python is reasonably similar to Matlab, but I guess that might be a YMMV type issue?

Comment: @KyleKanos I didn't know it was Python (one day, I will learn it). To large extent, I have some idea what is going on, but I don't feel very comfortable distillating an algorithm out of it without derivation.

Comment: Well it's changelog you've linked to, the full python file is [here](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/wigner.py)

Comment: For now, I decided working with the qutip package itself in python, which seems very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually used the Clenshaw-algorithm of the QuTiP toolbox mentioned above and it works adequately and fast for my considered density matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I implement it on mathematica by Laguerre polynomials 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qg9dW7oS73Y4gUUJCtdONvScDfBY2Rds/view?usp=drivesdk